# GSEvent and multiple fingers

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I am successful in monitoring raw touches using GSEvent by hooking sendEvent. How do I extract touch information when multiple fingers are involved?

Update 1: iOS 5.01

Update 2: I managed to do this by going over the allTouches set contained in the event passed. It works fine, but bogs down a when gesture recognizers kick in for a 4 or 5 finger event..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are kind of right. By overriding the sendEvent: method, and then getting the GSEvent from the UIEvent, you can get the underlying sytem information you are looking for. You could watch the "infoSize" field in the GSEvent record, which should tell you how many touches are involved in the event... But why use GSEvent? You could just put one big UIView in your application, set it's multiple touch interaction property as YES, override it's sendEvent method, and you should get every touch in there, even the 4 and 5 finger gestures. You can forward touches that are not important for you, and don't forward the ones that are not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to track gestures in every application, hence a tweak is required. I did it by hooking sendEvent and going over GSEventGetPathInfoAtIndex() and using allTouches.count as limit. What I found out is that SpringBoard really hates when you hook its sendEvent. It crashes after a running for a bit and you shake the device. I do check for hand events/mouse only. Strange

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer since it's the only on and on-topic :)

Comment: Yes, of course it crashes. The GSEventRecord you receive on a shake is smaller than the one you receive on any other situation. Therefore, when you access the "pathInfo" objects, your app crashes.

Comment: But how can simulate multi touch event?

Comment: This question is not about simulating touch events, it is about interpreting them.

Comment: @GeorgeAguirre, would you help to check this problem about simulating multi-touch, thank you very much.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907811/how-to-simulate-multi-touch-with-gsevent